# AppleID account sign in VirtualBox

Tags: icloud, macos, apple-id, virtualization, virtualbox

I managed to install El Capitan (not Sierra) in Virtual Box on my MBP running Sierra. Looks fine on the first view. One major problem is that I can not sign up with my own Apple (or any other test) ID within the VM. The sign in process keeps spinning and spinning. Is it because the host system IP is already using the Apple ID?
Installing Sierra into the box failed from scratch, but once the ID is up I want to try upgrading to Sierra.

Thanks,
EL

Comment: Interesting question. I've never come across this, so can't offer a definitive answer. However, one way to _test_ whether it's because of the IP is to install something like [TunnelBear](https://www.tunnelbear.com/) within your El Capitan installation. You can use it for free to connect to a VPN from a different location and route all traffic through that (thereby changing your IP address). Once you're connected, try signing in with your Apple ID again and see what happens. Report back here. If this solves the problem, you can even answer your own question which will help others! :)